# SASS/SCSS: Define variables based on other variables

Tags: sass

How does one define variables with the use of other variables in SASS?

This is how one could do it with LESS:

```
// import Google Material Colors
// returns variables ie @blue-500, @blue-400 etc
@import 'material.colors.less';

// base
@_color: 'blue';
@_secondary: 'amber';

// primary colors
@color-primary: ~"@{@{_color}-500}";
@color-primary-bright: ~"@{@{_color}-300}";
@color-primary-brighter: ~"@{@{_color}-200}";
@color-primary-brightest: ~"@{@{_color}-50}";

// secondary colors
@color-secondary: ~"@{@{_secondary}-500}";
@color-secondary-bright: ~"@{@{_secondary}-300}";
@color-secondary-brighter: ~"@{@{_secondary}-200}";
@color-secondary-brightest: ~"@{@{_secondary}-50}";
```

The LESS-way certainly isn't clean and dandy, but -- it works™
The idea is to set a base primary and then just set the other color(s) dynamically based on that.

I can't imagine that one would have to loop/map etc just to do this with SASS?(!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sass does not support dynamic variables, period.

You will need to use maps, but I'm not sure this will help you in this specific case (as you are already using external colors):

```sass
@import 'material.colors';

$colors: (
  primary: (
    default: $blue-500,
    bright: $blue-300,
    brighter: $blue-200,
    brightest: $blue-50
  ),
  secondary: (
    default: $amber-500,
    bright: $amber-300,
    brighter: $amber-200,
    brightest: $amber-50
  )
);

@function color($color, $brightness: default) {
  @return map-get(map-get($colors, $color), $brightness);
}

h1 {
  color: color(primary, bright);
  background-color: color(secondary);
}
```

Comment: This seems extraordinarily counter-intuitive? What lang doesn't support dynamic variables ... ? :) Maybe i should switch to something else. Also you pretty much destroyed the idea of just setting 'blue' and be done with it so the example provided is of little use since one then just as well could just set all variables manually.

Comment: It has been discussed for months, but if you're maintaining the whole code, everything could be done without dynamic variables (which add far more complexity to the compiler).

Comment: And yes, I understand the DRY is pulverized in my example :) That's because you're dealing with an external library that already defined variables. Defining everything yourself, you'd be able to get what you want with maps.

Comment: Pulverized is an understatement. :) I'm sorry, but your code looks even more terrible then the LESS-example. :) The conclusion seem to be: If you don't require the other stuff that SASS offers use somehing else. I'll accept your answer as 'Best' in a while if no one else wants to chime in (which seem unlikely).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it. You can use neat sass color functions and do what you need in a nice and clean way. Take a look at [lighten function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#lighten-instance_method) and even [darken function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#darken-instance_method), or at other color functions in general.

Basically, you do it like this:

```
$primary-color: #08f;

$primary-light-color: lighten($primary-color, 20%);
$primary-lighter-color: lighten($primary-color, 30%);
$primary-dark-color: darken($primary-color, 20%);
$primary-darker-color: darken($primary-color, 30%);
```

You can see this in action here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjXRjM?editors=1100#0

Or if you feel like it's a good idea, you could automate it a little with lists and loops. Take a look at this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-color-values-with-sass/, where its author gets through it. (To be honest, I'm not sure if that a good idea at all, as it easily may be hard to understand and maintain later. That's another topic, though.)

Comment: lighten/darken is not a way of using pre-defined variables such as the case first outlined. Unfortunately it seems that you have missed the point.